# Json from external file

Tags: json, bash, jq

I need to create a JSON file with the following contents:

```
{
    "destinationVersion":"4",
    "sourceVersion":"0",
    "props":{
       "METADATA_SIZE":"91669",
       "METADATA_HASH":"O7CLdR2j7qoD0RI2k1AGc8b+xoWYn20Ic24eZ1ZWUWE=",
       "FILE_SIZE":"980374602",
       "FILE_HASH":"+XW4QKN5Y4ynTx43m4NYbMuk1x3P91f1biAVZBpj4fI="
    }
 }
```

The main snag with the `props` block.
These values for `props` must be read from the text file.
In it they are in the following format:

```
FILE_HASH=+XW4QKN5Y4ynTx43m4NYbMuk1x3P91f1biAVZBpj4fI=
FILE_SIZE=980374602
METADATA_HASH=O7CLdR2j7qoD0RI2k1AGc8b+xoWYn20Ic24eZ1ZWUWE=
METADATA_SIZE=91669
```

My task is to read the file and somehow create the final JSON (append formatted text to `props` block).
I try to do this through jq, but I don’t know how to convert the file to be added to the final JSON. Preferred way - `bash + jq`

Comment: What have you tried? On this forum adding your own work to the question is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Q only indicates the source for the key=value strings, the following focuses on the conversion of these strings to a JSON object.

Invocation: jq -n -R -f program.jq props.txt

program.jq:

```
[inputs | capture("^(?<key>[^=]*)=(?<value>.*)")]
| from_entries
```

Using `inputs` here has several small advantages but is inessential.